# Matrix Similarity through Schur's Formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to solve the following exercise to prepare for qualifiers.  The purpose of this exercise is to get familiar with Schur's formula.  (This exercise is apparently very basic).

Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix with eigenvalues $a \pm ib$.  Then $A$ is similar to 
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
-b & a
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
The first step I have taken is to use the fact that $A$ is an $n \times n$ square matrix with complex entries.  Then $A$ can be expressed by
\begin{align}
A = QUQ^{*},
\end{align}
where $Q$ is unitary and $U$ is upper-triangular.  From here I want to start playing with the "Schur" stuff; which from my understanding is techniques such as:
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
I_{r} & 0 \\
-CA^{-1} & I_{n -r}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
0 & D - CA^{-1}B
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
For $A$ an $r \times r$ matrix, $B$ an $r \times (n -r)$ matrix, $C$ an $(n -r) \times r$ matrix , and $F$ an $(n - r) \times (n - r)$ matrix, where $A$ is given to be invertible.  Is this the right direction to head in?  I am a bit lost as to what use to always make out of the Schur formula, and how to look for it.

Please ask if any clarifications are needed.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not quite true.  See below.

In the case where b is non-zero it will be true.  That is because if a 2x2 matrix has two **distinct** eigenvalues then it will be similar to any other matrix with the same eigenvalues.

The only way I know for two matrices to have the same eigenvalues and not be similar is if their Jordan normal forms are not the same.  That is, the associated eigenvector space is different for the two matrices.  This could mean that one of these spaces has generalized eigenvalues and one does not; or that both have generalized eigenvalues but not of the same orders.

In the 2x2 case you have matrices like

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

and

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

which have the same eigenvalues, in both cases 1 with a multiplicity of 2.  However they are not similar.  Yet you could regard these eigenvalues as 1 $\pm$ 0i.

Comment: Thanks Betty.  I think we are to assume though that b is non-zero.

Comment: Of course you are supposed to assume b is not zero; but one should be careful.  Sorry I couldn't help with the Schur's formula stuff.